# Set timezone to EST in Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Can anyone advise how I change the timezone for my google app engine application? It's running python, I need to set the timezone so all datetime.now() etc work on EST timezone instead of the default?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at http://timezones.appspot.com/

You can not make `datetime.now()` to use your custom time zone but you can convert time as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [dateutil library](http://labix.org/python-dateutil):

```
datetime.datetime.now(dateutil.tz.tzutc())
```

...to get the now() time for UTC, for instance.